# MultiByteToWideChar converts (°) degree symbol to �

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode

I am trying to convert a string from ANSII to Wide char. I am using `CA2W(string,CP_UTF8)` which internally uses `MultiByteToWideChar`.

While debugging it shows that `MultiByteToWideChar` converts  ° degree symbol to �.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen...

Comment: I am not able to understand your comment, please elaborate.

Comment: Post the code you are using, or nobody will be able to understand the problem or offer any advice.

Comment: does that include the paranthesis? that is, is it the `(°)` that is being converted or is it only the `°` that is being converted?

Comment: Hehe, I just read the most recent Old New Thing a few minutes ago: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/17/10349955.aspx

Comment: I'd also be interested in how he has determined this.  I've seen � when the character wasn't present in the font, or for an illegal encoding, or something like that---an artifact of the renderer, at any rate, and _not_ something encoded in the text being displayed.

Comment: James, U+FFFD Replacement Character is just a way of signalling an invalid character in a Unicode string. This can happen not only when rendering, also when converting from an encoding to Unicode (in the reverse direction you usually get a question mark or an approximation of the original character). You can quickly try it out in PowerShell: `[text.encoding]::utf8.GetString([text.encoding]::Default.GetBytes('abcädef'))`

Comment: The original bytes are not a utf-8 encoding.  Try CP_ACP instead of CP_UTF8.

Comment: Are you sure that `string` was `°` *in UTF-8*?  It seems kind of unlikely to me that the debugger showed you `°` since Windows lets you use `CP_UTF8` only in the context of conversion, not as an active code page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MultiByteToWideChar converts from a given encoding to UTF-16 (ie wide char). You need to make sure that you specify the correct encoding of the source, which probably is NOT UTF-8.

Due to the way UTF-8 is encoded anything over ASCII 0x7f indicates that the BYTE is part of a multi-byte character sequence and unless that sequence is correctly specified will result in a '?'. More information on the encoding of multi-byte sequences can be found here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Basically, your source encoding is probably based on the current code page of the system and so you need to specify CP_ACP when calling MultiByteToWideChar.

Comment: thanks there is problem is source.